# publishing Filemaker (database software) data on Wordpress website

Tags: mysql, import, odbc, filemaker

We would like to be able to publish Filemaker data on our Wordpress website. The website is up and running and the filemaker database is set up. We do not need a live connection between both systems so we chose to export the FM data to .csv so we can import it to the mysql database on the server and from there we would like to display in on the website.

Now are my questions, since this kind of development is new to us:

can I setup an automated import to the mysql database from a source like dropbox or something? For example can we make the mysql database import and overwrite the existing database each 24 hours from a .csv file located somewhere? We need this automated overwrite option because the FM data changes often and we need up to date info on the website)

How can we display the data from the mysql database on the WP frontend?

I've been looking into this myself and couldn't find any clear answers or guides. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

(btw, I know there are table plugins I can use for WP but they do not fulfill our needs, and I think it's exciting to do it all by ourself with help from this great community)

**Update 01**

I've successfully connected FM with my MySQL db using ODBC and can now select tables from the MySQL db in FM's relational graph.
I was wondering how I can write the data from my existing FM file to the MySQL db using ODBC, can anybody help me on this? 
I would like to display the data in some MySQL tables so I can fetch them using php on my website.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you plan to update your MySQL database directly from Filemaker, your question is not Filemaker-related at all: a .csv file is a .csv file, no matter how it was generated.

Comment: Boris looking at your other questions and you seem to know PHP.  Why are you trying to export to something as crude as csv and then import it (which but the way won't work in an automated fashion the way you described it.  You can't run an automated task from Dropbox.)?  Why wouldn't you just write a SOAP request or use the web services capabilities to write your own script since you seem to know how to code already?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right, I do know php, but just basic stuff and im still eager to learn. This means lot's of things are still new to me, so is this topic. So you're saying the .csv dropbox thing won't work? and you suggest a so called SOAP Request? I have never heard of this and will look into it. In the mean time I would be very grateful if you elaborate this topic a little bit more so I can do more specific research. Thanks!

Comment: I found thus guide, this is what how do you guys think about that? milanm.com/?p=491

Comment: You say that you can select SQL tables in FM's graph. This sounds like using ESS (External SQL Sources. There it is easy: you can simply edit SQL data like FileMaker data.  Create new records, enter field data and so on.

Comment: True! But I have an existing FM database hosted on FM server and my SQL db is empty (apart from the standard Wordpress tables). My question is how can I get FM to sync selected fields to a MySQL database? Im now using export in FM and import in MySQL and replace content in MySQL. But how can I skip this step if I would like?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write directly into (and read from) a remote MySQL database from FileMaker via ODBC.

You need an MySQL account which allows remote access. There are providers where this is not allowed.

On the local box the odbc driver needs to be installed. On Win you can use the open source version (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/), on Mac it works better with the Actual Tech (http://www.actualtech.com/de/product_opensourcedatabases.php) drivers.

An odbc system dsn (not user dsn) is set up. Be sure to use the 32-bit odbc manager on Win.

Now you can create the external data source within FileMaker and read and write into MySQL tables.

Comment: I haven't been able to locate a single Filemaker host that will allow an ODBC connection without updgrading to dedicated hosting, have you?  Curious.  He also wanted to do this on his own so even if there is a host out there I think a direct live connection might be a bit too advanced.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Wouldn't this require a live connection like mentioned by ThisisDesign? if not, can you tell me a little bit more about the windows one, like what steps I need to take, or point me to a guide. This is all new to me and I'm sure I can handle it but only with help from you guys. Thanks!

Comment: I found thus guide, this is what how do you guys think about that? http://www.milanm.com/?p=491 That's what you were trying to say Jens Teich? right?

Comment: That link is exactly what I was talking about, yes

Comment: @JensTeich, I've established a connection, can you help me out some more? please see my first updated post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have made the connection to the MySQL database, and you can see the shadow tables, you can write to the fields directly via Filemaker layouts. It's as simple as that.
Once the layout contains the fields from the MySQL database you can move through records, find stuff all as if the data were native in your FM database. Of course, for more automated processing, you can create scripts, relationships etc and manipulate/synchronise data. Be warned though, the connection speed can limit complex relationships and large databases. I would advise 'baby steps'.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that completely. Unfortunately that does not yet answer my question I guess, because like stated in my post and comments, Im using and existing FM file and need to copy it to MySQL. Im not staring from scratch.... So my question is: how can I get my Filemaker db copied to MySQL? once that is done I can work from there... Do you understand?